# refresh Drop-in UI after error - Braintree/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I am using the Braintree api and its Drop in UI which is working fine until i get an unsuccessful response.

The drop in ui is not refreshing (maybe there is something i need to do) which results a user not being able to enter new card details. I don't want to persist the card details, just show the form again

I am not using turbolinks

```
def new
  gon.client_token = generate_client_token
end

def create
  @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            amount: amount,
            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
            customer: {
              first_name: params[:first_name],
              last_name: params[:last_name]
            options: {
              submit_for_settlement: true
            }
          )
  if @result.success?
    redirect_to thank_you_path
  else
    @error_message = BraintreeErrors::Errors.new.error_message(@result)
    flash.now[:alert] = @error_message
    gon.client_token = generate_client_token
    render :new
  end
end
```

Is there something I need to do to get this to work?

Update

As in the comments I could redirect to the new action, reloading my page, which would then show my drop in ui form, so to expand on this question what if I want to persist the data that as user has filled in on another part of my form, like name, address etc , again i am not worried about the card information

I use a form_tag

```
<%= form_tag transactions_path, class: 'form-small form' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :first_name, "", placeholder: 'First Name', required: false %>
  <%= text_field_tag :last_name, "", placeholder: 'First Name', required: false %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered redirecting to the new action instead of rendering it's template?

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu I have updated my question, how could i persist form data in this scenario ?

Comment: You can simply pass it over as instance variables, like you do with the client_token.

Comment: thanks, is this possible when using a form_tag ? if you could provide an example? that would be much appreciated and help me understand, i can grab individual params with `params[:first_name]` but i need to grab the whole form really dont I ?

Comment: think im onto something as i can access them through the `@result` object like `@result.transaction.customer_details`. just how to get them to populate the form now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your `create` action `redirect_to` the `new` action.

```
def new
  @first_name = params[:first_name] if params[:first_name].present?
  @last_name = params[:last_name] if params[:last_name].present?
end

def create
  ...

  if @result.success?
    redirect_to thank_you_path
  else
    redirect_to new_path (
      first_name: params[:first_name], 
      last_name: params[:last_name]
    )
  end
end
```

Then you need to update the form so it picks the 'default' values

```
<%= form_tag transactions_path, class: 'form-small form' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :first_name, @first_name, placeholder: 'First Name', required: false %>
  <%= text_field_tag :last_name, @last_name, placeholder: 'First Name', required: false %>
<% end %>
```

---

If you have many such properties it will be cleaner if you bundle them all in a `customer_details` object. Then in your view you can do

```
<%= form_for @customer_details do |c| %>
  <%= c.text_field :first_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, so initially a `form_tag` but after an error switch to a `form_for` with new object ?

Comment: No, the view should be identical in both cases. I just showed you two different approaches. One with simple instance variables and `form_tag` and another with an object that bundles the properties inside and `form_for`.

Comment: ah ok I see, if i redirect though after declaring `@first_name` wont that just be nil in the new action? or am i misunderstanding ?

Comment: should i save this info in a session variable instead?

Comment: You should avoid using session where possible.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for persisting the data ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, you have helped and i have learned something